# Match numbers in shell

Tags: shell

How to match any number proceeding a set of characters in shell script ? 
Eg: abc.123, abc.23456 .... should be able to match abc.XXXXXX

Looking for something like `find / -iname abc.[]` , here it should match only numbers.

Comment: Would you explain more? Do you have a file and you want to find matches the form in that file? Or do you want to find all files that match the form in a directory?

Comment: Have you tried `find / -iname "abc.[0-9]*"`?